# `pm2 web` command not found. How to start pm2 web server?

Tags: pm2

I'm using pm2 version 4.4.0 and trying to start the pm2 web server.

Is 'pm2 web' deprecated? If yes, how do I get the CPU and memory metrics using pm2 API?

I am trying to create a Grafana dashboard for pm2 following this article:
https://medium.com/@nikunjd.np/pm2-microservices-monitoring-with-grafana-influxdb-54fb6f8b5d2d